# How do you update a time uniform inside a filter or fragment shader in PIXI.JS?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am making use of a fragment shader or filter in PIXI.JS on an image sprite that basically sets the whole container to red. Passing the `time` uniform sets everything to black instead of changing the color between red and black. Any hint on why it does not update as expected?

Thanks!

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

// Variables
const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
let uniforms = {
  time: {
    type: 'f',
    value: 0
  }
};

// Fragment shader
const frag = /*glsl*/`
  precision mediump float;

  uniform float time;

  void main() {
    float t = sin(time);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(t, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
`;

// Create renderer
const renderer = new PIXI.Renderer({
  width,
  height
});
const stage = new PIXI.Container();
// Add renderer to DOM
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

// Create image sprite from texture
const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('path-to-image');
const image = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
image.position.set(width / 2, height / 2);
image.scale.set(0.5);
image.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
// Add sprite to stage/scene
stage.addChild(image);

// Create ticker
const ticker = new PIXI.Ticker();
ticker.add(animate);
ticker.start();

// Animates renderer
function animate() {
  filter.uniforms.time.value += 1/60;
  renderer.render(stage);
}

// Create filter that adds fragment shader
let filter = new PIXI.Filter(null, frag, uniforms);
image.filters = [ filter ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this exact problem 1.5 year later.

For me, the solution was to not set the uniform as an object. It seems PIXI handles some conversion here on the fly. Try replacing the following

```
let uniforms = {
  time: {
    type: 'f',
    value: 0
  }
};
```

with simply

```
let uniforms = {
  time: 0 // or 0.0
};
```

[Look here for a complete example using uniforms](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters-advanced/custom.js)